# Extracting date from file group name and converting to date fails when filtering

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

In sys.sysfielgroups I have a list of filegroups with dates in them, and I'm trying to extract these dates.  Here's an example list of the file groups:

> Event_Header_Daily_LeftNull_FG
>
> Event_Header_Daily_2018_08_07_FG
>
> Event_Header_Daily_2018_08_08_FG
>
> Event_Header_Daily_2018_08_09_FG
>
> Event_Header_Daily_2018_08_10_FG  2018-08-10

This is the query that I'm trying to run.  As you can see, I'm trying to get any file group older than today's date:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(

    SELECT 
        groupname,
        CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(groupname, 'Event_Header_Daily_', ''), '_FG',''), '_', '-') AS DATE) AS dt
    FROM sys.sysfilegroups
    WHERE groupname LIKE 'Event_Header_Daily_%'
        AND groupname NOT IN ('Event_Header_Daily_LeftNull_FG')
) a
WHERE dt < GETDATE()
```

If i run the subselect without filtering the results, the query runs just fine.  However, when running the whole query I get the 7th, 8th, and 9th and the query errors out, stating:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

As far as I can tell this should just work, but it doesn't and I'm at a loss as to why.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that for some values the resulting trim isn't a date so it can't be converted to one.

This is your current `REPLACE` function:

```
DECLARE @FileGroupName VARCHAR(100) = 'Event_Header_Daily_2018_08_09_FG'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FileGroupName, 'Event_Header_Daily_', ''), '_FG',''), '_', '-')
-- Result: 2018-08-09
```

This is the value in which it won't work (you filtered one but there might be others similar to this one):

```
DECLARE @FileGroupName VARCHAR(100) = 'Event_Header_Daily_LeftNull_FG'
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@FileGroupName, 'Event_Header_Daily_', ''), '_FG',''), '_', '-')
-- Result: LeftNull

SELECT CAST('LeftNull' AS DATE)
-- Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

`TRY_PARSE()` function won't throw an error whenever the cast can't be done, it will return `NULL`.

```
SELECT TRY_CAST('LeftNull' AS DATE)
-- Result: NULL
```

You should switch your explicit `CAST` with a `TRY_PARSE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(

    SELECT 
        groupname,
        TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(groupname, 'Event_Header_Daily_', ''), '_FG',''), '_', '-') AS DATE) AS dt
    FROM sys.sysfilegroups
    WHERE groupname LIKE 'Event_Header_Daily_%'
        AND groupname NOT IN ('Event_Header_Daily_LeftNull_FG')
) a
WHERE dt < GETDATE()
```

If you want to know which values are giving casting problems, you can check where the `TRY_PARSE IS NULL`.

```
SELECT 
    groupname,
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(groupname, 'Event_Header_Daily_', ''), '_FG',''), '_', '-') AS dt
FROM sys.sysfilegroups
WHERE groupname LIKE 'Event_Header_Daily_%'
    AND groupname NOT IN ('Event_Header_Daily_LeftNull_FG')
    AND TRY_PARSE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(groupname, 'Event_Header_Daily_', ''), '_FG',''), '_', '-') AS DATE) IS NULL
```